# Hikvision ISAPI

Tags: isapi, hikvision

**Can some help me how to add a person to access group using ISAPI,**

I have implemented some features such as addPerson, captureFingerData, applyFingerDataToPerson. the only remaining thing is how to add that person to access group

I search the api endpoint but didn't find it